# Place figure at bottom of this page or the top of the next page

Tags: floats, positioning

If a figure will fit on the bottom of the page, it will also fit at the top of the page and will wind up there (barring certain circumstances).  The best I have come up with is to set topnumber to 0 (default).

Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everypage,afterpage}

\setcounter{topnumber}{0}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\lipsum[3-4]% for top of next page

\AddThispageHook{\stepcounter{topnumber}}
\afterpage{\addtocounter{topnumber}{-1}}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\rule{\textwidth}{.2\textheight}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you simply do `\begin{figure}[t]` ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? (sorry if it's clear to everyone else, I personally am not sure what he wants) I understand the question that you don't want a figure to be placed at the top of the page, but at the bottom. Is that correct? Are there circumstances where you want a figure to be placed automatically at the top? If not, you could redefine the default figure placement to not include `t`, but only `bp` or `hbp`.

Comment: @Skillmon -  I do NOT want the figure at the top of THIS page, but the top of the next page is fine.   [ht] is a good approximation to what I am trying to accomplish.  BTW, [b!t] seems to behave identical to [tb].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution converts every [b] figure to a [tb] figure at the end of every page.  I'm not sure what all the bit flags do, but [t] is 50, [b] is 52 and [tb] is 54,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everypage}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \def\reset#1{\ifnum\count#1=52 \global\count#1=54\fi}% convert [b] to [bt]
  \let\@elt=\reset
  \@deferlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3-4]% for op of next page

\begin{figure}[b]
\rule{\textwidth}{.2\textheight}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-12]

\end{document}
```

---

A much simpler solution is now available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\lipsum[3-4]% for top of next page

\suppressfloats[t]
\begin{figure}
\rule{\textwidth}{.2\textheight}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-12]

\end{document}
```