# PlainTeX: Float(s) lost with custom output routine

Tags: floats, plain-tex, output-routine

I use PlainTex because I like its simplicity and because I understand almost all lines of its code. When I look at the output routine of LaTeX I only understand a little bit.

So I trie to add floats on my own to PlainTex, my first trial can be seen here:
[How to keep the order of floats in Plain TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458707/how-to-keep-the-order-of-floats-in-plain-tex)

I would like to get a similar float handling as in LaTeX but with the possibility to understand the code. As there is no documentation for more complex output routines I have a question now.

Look at my MWE:

```
% Plain LuaTeX (for other engines: \protected\def\glet{\global\let})
\font\testfont=cmr17 at 20 pt% to show the problem better

\testfont
\normalbaselineskip24pt
\normalbaselines

\catcode`\@=11
\parskip\z@
\raggedbottom
% The sizes have to be calculated in \output.
\newdimen\fullhsize
\newdimen\fullvsize
\fullhsize\hsize
\fullvsize\vsize

\newdimen\@colroom
\@colroom\fullvsize
% Float boxes as in latex.ltx
\newinsert\bx@A
\newinsert\bx@B
\newinsert\bx@C
\newinsert\bx@D
\newinsert\bx@E
\newinsert\bx@F
\newinsert\bx@G
\newinsert\bx@H
\newinsert\bx@I
\newinsert\bx@J
% Float handling parameters:
\newcount\@topnum
\newcount\maxtopnum \maxtopnum\thr@@
\newdimen\@toproom
\newdimen\maxtoproom \maxtoproom.4\fullvsize

\newcount\@botnum
\newcount\maxbotnum \maxbotnum\tw@
\newdimen\@botroom
\newdimen\maxbotroom \maxbotroom.3\fullvsize

\newif\if@insert
\newif\if@trybottom
\def\@empty{}
% Similar to latex.ltx:
\def\@freelist{\bx@A\bx@B\bx@C\bx@D\bx@E\bx@F\bx@G\bx@H\bx@I\bx@J}
\let\@toplist\@empty
\let\@botlist\@empty
\let\@deferlist\@empty
% List handling macros:
\def\@additem#1#2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\@takefirstitem#1{%
    \expandafter\@@takefirstitem#1!%
    \glet#1=\@tempa}

\def\@@takefirstitem#1#2!{\gdef\@currbox{#1}%
    \def\@tempa{#2}}
% A primitive definiton of a float:
\def\float#1{% #1=1 -> top float, 2 -> top or bottom float, 3 -> bottom float
    \@takefirstitem\@freelist
    \global\count\@currbox#1\relax
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \parskip\z@}

\def\endfloat{\par\vskip\z@\egroup
    \penalty-40000\relax
    \dimen@\prevdepth
    \vbox{}
    \prevdepth\dimen@
    \penalty-30000\relax}

\def\@nextboxcnt{% type of the next float on deferlist
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \count\expandafter\@firstofmany\@deferlist!}

\def\@nextboxht{% height of the next float on deferlist
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \ht\expandafter\@firstofmany\@deferlist!}

\def\@firstofmany#1#2!{#1}

% Output routine
\output{\myoutput}
\def\myoutput{%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-40000\relax
%   \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{\unvbox\footins}\fi
    \global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
    \else
    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-30000\relax
    \setbox8\box\@cclv
    \unvbox\@ne
    \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{\unvbox\footins}\fi
    %\unvbox\@cclv
    %
    \ifcase\count\@currbox\or%1 top float
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@ \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@toproom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \else
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \or%2 top or bottom float
    \@inserttrue
    \@trybottomfalse
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
    \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@toproom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \else
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@trybottomtrue
    \else \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox\fi
    \fi
    %
    \if@trybottom
    \@inserttrue
    \ifdim\ht\@currbox>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
  \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botroom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \else
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \fi
    %
    \or%3 bottom float
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\ht\@currbox>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
  \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botroom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \else
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %    
    \fi
    %
    \else
    \shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
    \advancepageno
    % Prepare next page/column:
    \global\@colroom\fullvsize
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \global\@toproom\z@
    \global\@botnum\z@
    \global\@botroom\z@
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty\else
    % Top floats
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<\z@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt>\tw@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
   \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\@nextboxht\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@takefirstitem\@deferlist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@toproom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\empty\else
    % Bottom floats:
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<\tw@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\@nextboxht>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
   \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\@nextboxht\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@takefirstitem\@deferlist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botroom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    %
    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-\@MM \dosupereject\fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty<-30000\relax
        \global\vsize\maxdimen\else\global\vsize\@colroom\fi}

\def\pagebody{\vbox to\fullvsize{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}}

%\pagecontents that insert top and bottom floats:
\def\pagecontents{\ifx\@toplist\@empty\else
    \loop
    \@takefirstitem\@toplist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@freelist\@currbox
    \box\@currbox
    \unless\ifx\@toplist\@empty\repeat
    \fi
    %
    \dimen@=\dp\@cclv \unvbox\@cclv % open up \box255
    %
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty\else
    \loop
    \@takefirstitem\@botlist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@freelist\@currbox
    \box\@currbox
    \unless\ifx\@botlist\@empty\repeat
    \fi
    \ifvoid\footins\else % footnote info is present
    \vskip\skip\footins
    \footnoterule
    \unvbox\footins\fi
    \ifr@ggedbottom \kern-\dimen@ \vfil \fi}

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\float1 ABCD1 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD2 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD3 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD4 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD5 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD6 \vskip20pt\endfloat

2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.%

\float1 ABCD7 \vskip20pt\endfloat% disappears

\float1 ABCD8 \vskip20pt\endfloat

3. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\bye
```

As you can see in the picture the 7th float disappears. This is a known problem near pagebreaks. I know that LaTeX fixes this by adding 2 penalties. I tried this, too, with `\penalty-40000` but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

(Edit: a better output routine, same result.)

[image]

Comment: Probably not helpful, but ...  Penalties with an absolute value greater than 10000 (positive or negative) are not treated differently than 10000.  So `-40000` really isn't any more effective than `-10000`.

Comment: But LaTeX adds something like `\penalty-10004 \vbox{} \penalty-10003` after a float in vertical mode so that floats near a page break are not lost. But this cannot be all because my MWE does not work. But the code in `latex.ltx` contains so much macros, so I am not able to identify the relevant code lines.

Comment: If you set \showthe\outputpenalty at the begin of your output routine
you will see that with the seventh float TeX does a forced output,
i.e., outputpenalty is 10000, not -30000. So the path taken is to
output a page and to reassign @currbox. Therefore the assignment of
the seventh box is lost.

What to do? Note if the \@currbox is emptied in the output routine or
not.

Comment: There are several aspects of your code that I do not understand, for
example, why do use newinsert when only the box is needed?

In general a penalty of -10000 triggers the output routine, but you
can use other values to indicate why the output routine is called. You
use -30000 for your float environment. A value of -40000 does not make
a difference. But you can use -10001 if you have something else than
\float and you want to do something special in the output routine. So
you should really use -10001 instead of -30000.

Comment: I use `\newinsert` because I need the `\box` and the `\count`. Yes, of coure I can write `\penalty-10001` instead of `\penalty-30000` but what is the difference?

Comment: But thank you very much. Now I know what I have done wrong. :)

Comment: Of course, it is a convention. Plain TeX uses the penalty -20000 for
the supereject. All values less than -20000 are used for this too as
the code is `\ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000\else\dosupereject\fi`. You
changed that code too, so it is not a problem with -30000.

But your code doesn't work if you add four additional `\float` lines
just above the `\bye`. The last one is not output. The `\dosuperejct` must
do more.

Comment: No you do not use \count\bx@A, for example, in the code shown. It is a
scaling factor that has to be set once and is used by TeX internally;
in this case its value should be 1000. Your code does not need it as
you do not treat the inserts as inserts.

Comment: I know, `\dosupereject` ist my next project... Then floats that are allowed to be placed where they are called and multicolumn output with dblfloats and a float barrier. There is still much to do and of course I could use LaTeX but I want to do it on my own. So I have the chance to understand the code. LaTeX has so many macros without a documentation.

Comment: I do use `\count\bx@A`. Not directly but in my definition of `\float` the is the line `\global\count\@currbox#1\relax`. It is set to 1 for a top float, 2 for a flexible (top or bottom) float and 3 for a bottom float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When output routine is called by TeX `\outputpenalty` is 10000 (except in
the endgame) and TeX has the command `\supereject` which uses the value
-20000. Every penalty value less than -10000 can be used for the output routine
and it is suggested to use values -10001, -10002, etc. if the output routine
shall be notified why it is called.

The TeXbook, Appendix D, page 400 states:

> Sometimes an output routine needs to know why it was invoked, so
>   there's a problem of communicating information from the rest of the
>   program. TeX provides general `\mark` operations, but marks don't
>   always yield the right sorts of clues. Then there's `\outputpenalty`,
>   which can be tested to see what penalty occurred at a breakpoint; any
>   penalty of -10000, -10001, -10002, or less, forces the output
>   routine to act, hence different penalty values can be used to pass
>   different messages.

OK; you use -30000 to trigger the output routine if a box was filled with
a float. In the output routine this outputpenalty is checked and the box
is placed in one of two lists. Now TeX has read the seventh float and it
sees that the material that was collected exceeds what it needs. If you
activate tracingpages you see the line

> % t=565.88889 plus 60.0 g=542.21104 b=* p=-30000 c=*

which has infinite cost. So TeX breaks earlier; the previous lines are

> % t=493.88889 plus 60.0 g=542.21104 b=52 p=0 c=52#
>
> % t=517.88889 plus 60.0 g=542.21104 b=7 p=0 c=7#
>
> % t=541.88889 plus 60.0 g=542.21104 b=0 p=150 c=150

and the break is made with cost c=7 and the outputpenalty is set to 10000. The
box bx@G is filled but it is not emptied in the output routine. @currbox gets new
content and the connection to bx@G is lost.

On the new page TeX starts with

> %% goal height=542.21104, max depth=4.0
>
> % t=13.88889 plus 60.0 g=542.21104 b=10000 p=150 c=100000#
>
> % t=37.88889 plus 60.0 g=542.21104 b=10000 p=-30000 c=-30000#

because there is the line `\float ABCD7 \vskip20pt\endfloat` to
finish. But now @currbox contains bx@F not bx@G. This box is permantly lost and
will never be used again as it wasn't placed on any list. bx@F appears later twice in freelist.

How to fix this?
Create a newif `\if@currboxfilled` and set it true in `\endfloat` after `\egroup`. Next
put `\if@currboxfilled` before `\ifx\@deferlist\@empty`. Then
replace the `\else` after the then-case of the -30000 by:

```
    \global\@currboxfilledfalse
    \fi
%
    \else
    \if@currboxfilled
       \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
       \global\@currboxfilledfalse
    \fi
```

If TeX is called with an outputpenalty different from -30000 but a box was
filled then it is placed on the @deferlist.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Udo Wermuth I it is clear now that the macro `\@currbox` is multiply used in the output routine. So in this case it gets another meaning. If I use an own macro for each case, the problem disappears, too:

Full MWE:

```
\font\testfont=cmr17 at 20 pt

\testfont
\normalbaselineskip24pt
\normalbaselines

\catcode`\@=11

\parskip\z@
\raggedbottom

\newdimen\fullhsize
\newdimen\fullvsize

\fullhsize\hsize
\fullvsize\vsize

\newdimen\@colroom
\@colroom\fullvsize

\newinsert\bx@A
\newinsert\bx@B
\newinsert\bx@C
\newinsert\bx@D
\newinsert\bx@E
\newinsert\bx@F
\newinsert\bx@G
\newinsert\bx@H
\newinsert\bx@I
\newinsert\bx@J

\newcount\@topnum
\newcount\maxtopnum \maxtopnum\thr@@
\newdimen\@toproom
\newdimen\maxtoproom \maxtoproom.4\fullvsize

\newcount\@botnum
\newcount\maxbotnum \maxbotnum\tw@
\newdimen\@botroom
\newdimen\maxbotroom \maxbotroom.3\fullvsize

\newcount\@dbltopnum
\newcount\maxdbltopnum \maxdbltopnum\tw@
\newdimen\@dbltoproom
\newdimen\maxdbltoproom \maxdbltoproom.4\fullvsize

\newcount\@botnum
\newcount\maxbotnum \maxbotnum\tw@
\newdimen\@botroom
\newdimen\maxbotroom \maxbotroom.3\fullvsize

\newcount\@dblbotnum
\newcount\maxdblbotnum \maxdblbotnum\tw@
\newdimen\@dblbotroom
\newdimen\maxdblbotroom \maxdblbotroom.3\fullvsize

\newif\if@insert
\newif\if@trybottom

\def\@empty{}

\def\@freelist{\bx@A\bx@B\bx@C\bx@D\bx@E\bx@F\bx@G\bx@H\bx@I\bx@J}
\let\@toplist\@empty
\let\@botlist\@empty
\let\@deferlist\@empty

\def\@additem#1#2{% #1: list, #2: token
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\@takenextbox#1#2{% #1: macro for storing the box, #2: list
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \expandafter\@@takenextbox#2!%
    \glet#2=\@tempb}

\def\@@takenextbox#1#2!{\expandafter\gdef\@tempa{#1}%
    \def\@tempb{#2}}

\def\float#1{%
    \@takenextbox\@currbox\@freelist
    \global\count\@currbox#1\relax
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@}

\def\endfloat{\par\vskip\z@\egroup
    \penalty-40000\relax
    \dimen@\prevdepth
    \vbox{}
    \prevdepth\dimen@
    \penalty-30000\relax}

\def\@nextboxcnt{% type (count) of the next float on \@deferlist
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \count\expandafter\@firstofmany\@deferlist!}

\def\@nextboxht{% height of the next float on deferlist
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \ht\expandafter\@firstofmany\@deferlist!}

\def\@firstofmany#1#2!{#1}

\output{\myoutput}
\def\myoutput{%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-40000\relax
    \global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
    \else
    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-30000\relax
    \setbox8\box\@cclv
    \unvbox\@ne
    \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{\unvbox\footins}\fi
    %
    \ifcase\count\@currbox\or%1
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
      \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@toproom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \else
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \or%2
    \@inserttrue
    \@trybottomfalse
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
    \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@toproom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \else
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@trybottomtrue
    \else \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox\fi
    \fi
    %
    \if@trybottom
    \@inserttrue
    \ifdim\ht\@currbox>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
      \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botroom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \else
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \fi
    %
    \or%3
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\ht\@currbox>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
      \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\ht\@currbox\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botroom\ht\@currbox
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \else
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %    
    \fi
    %
    \else
    \shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
    \advancepageno
    %
    \global\@colroom\fullvsize
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \global\@toproom\z@
    \global\@botnum\z@
    \global\@botroom\z@
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty\else
    % Top floats, do not use \@currbox here!
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<\z@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt>\tw@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
       \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\@nextboxht\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@takenextbox\@nextbox\@deferlist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@toplist\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@toproom\ht\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\empty\else
    % Bottom floats:
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<\tw@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\@nextboxht>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
       \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\@nextboxht\relax \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@takenextbox\@nextbox\@deferlist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@botlist\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@botroom\ht\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    %
    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-\@MM \dosupereject\fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty<-30000\relax
        \global\vsize\maxdimen\else\global\vsize\@colroom\fi}

\def\pagebody{\vbox to\fullvsize{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}}

\def\pagecontents{\ifx\@toplist\@empty\else% Do not use \@currbox here!
    \loop
    \@takenextbox\@nexttopbox\@toplist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@freelist\@nexttopbox
    \box\@nexttopbox
    \unless\ifx\@toplist\@empty\repeat
    \fi
    %
    \dimen@=\dp\@cclv \unvbox\@cclv % open up \box255
    %
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty\else
    \loop
    \@takenextbox\@nextbotbox\@botlist
    \expandafter\@additem\expandafter\@freelist\@nextbotbox
    \box\@nextbotbox
    \unless\ifx\@botlist\@empty\repeat
    \fi
    \ifvoid\footins\else % footnote info is present
    \vskip\skip\footins
    \footnoterule
    \unvbox\footins\fi
    \ifr@ggedbottom \kern-\dimen@ \vfil \fi}

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\float1 ABCD1 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD2 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD3 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD4 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD5 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD6 \vskip20pt\endfloat

2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\float1 ABCD7 \vskip20pt\endfloat% works now

\float1 ABCD8 \vskip20pt\endfloat

3. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\bye
```