# Figure placement problem

Tags: floats

I've encountered a very weird problem with the placement of my figures. I would like the figure to be at the very bottom of the page. When I write this code

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{Bilder/zeeman-aufspaltung}
\caption{blabla \cite{experimentalphysik3}} \label{f:zeeman-aufspaltung}
\end{figure}
Diese Aufspaltung nennt man normale Zeeman-Aufspaltung oder auch den normalen Zeeman-Effekt. Der Abstand der Zeeman-Niveaus beträgt dabei
\begin{equation}
\Delta E_m=E_m-E_{m-1}=\mu_B \cdot B \,.
\end{equation}
```

it places the figure above the text and the equation at the bottom of the page like so:
[image]

However, when I write the same code, only in a different order (first the text and the equation, then the figure),

```
Diese Aufspaltung nennt man normale Zeeman-Aufspaltung oder auch den normalen Zeeman-Effekt. Der Abstand der Zeeman-Niveaus beträgt dabei
\begin{equation}
\Delta E_m=E_m-E_{m-1}=\mu_B \cdot B \,.
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{Bilder/zeeman-aufspaltung}
\caption{blabla \cite{experimentalphysik3}} \label{f:zeeman-aufspaltung}
\end{figure}
```

it doesn't place the figure at the bottom of the page (where I want it to be), but on the next page.

[image]
There suddenly doesn't seem to be enough space for exactly the same code. I have to make the figure a lot smaller (much smaller than I want it to be), for it to be placed below the equation on the same page. Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how it can be fixed? Thx a lot.

My preamble is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref}
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup{format=plain} \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalsize\bfseries}
```

Comment: `\begin{figure}[h]` is more or less a request to position the figure at the end of the document (that's what would have happened in latex2.09) in latex2e it is detected and latex most likely warned you that it was changing it to [ht], the main effect of `[h]` is to stop the float being placed at the top of the page (not t) or the bottom 9no b) or on a page of figures (no p) so if it does not fit at that exact point (eg because it corresponds to a point to far don the page) ten the figure is not allowed anywhere.

Comment: If you want a float at the bottom, simply use the option " `[b]`ottom ", not  the option " `[h]`ere if possible", i.e., use `\begin{figure}[b] ... \end[figure]`, placing this float enough far of the probable point of page break, since otherwise it could be placed at the bottom of the next page.  In general, you should avoid use any option, and only *on the final version*, if needed, set the largest possible set of options  (e.g.,  some like `[tbp]` instead of only `[b]`), being aware that the more you force  the float position, the harder will be for LaTeX find a good place for next floats.

Comment: (Off-topic) Why don't use create that figure with LaTeX?

Comment: Actually, [tb] will always go to the top of the page unless there are 2 figures there already.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page?r=SearchResults&s=1|50.4412

Comment: As to your question, there is space at the end of the equation which gets absorbed at the bottom of the page, but possibly not if followed by a float.  Try `\vskip-\belowdisplayskip` after the equation.