# Is it possible to apply additional restrictions on float placement?

Tags: floats, two-column, double-sided

I'm currently working on a `twoside`,`twocolumns` document and have a certain float (covering the entirety of a column) which, for aestetic purposes, should only go on an outer column; so first column on even pages, second column on odd pages.

So far I've tried controlling its position through controlling when it's first seen through `afterpage`, which kinda works but is far from consistent.

Comment: You could modify \@floatplacement to set \@topnum and \@botnum to 0 when \if@firstcolumn is true.  See source2r from CTAN.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That would affect all (single-column) floats though, I assume?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I know?

Comment: It will not affect [h] or [p] floats.  I'm not sure how to turn off [p] floats.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's all fine, my issue is that it affects all single-column floats that are b and/or t.

Comment: It will also not stop [!] (which ignores topnumber and bottomnumber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it works.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\makeatletter
\def\@floatplacement{\if@firstcolumn
  \global\@topnum=0
  \global\@botnum=0
  \@fpmin=2\@colht
\else
  \global\@topnum=\c@topnumber
  \global\@botnum=\c@bottomnumber
  \@fpmin=\floatpagefraction\@colht
\fi
\global\@toproom=\topfraction\@colht
\global\@botroom=\bottomfraction\@colht
\global\@colnum=\c@totalnumber}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
  \caption{Test Figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tb]
  \caption{Test Table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \rule{.9\columnwidth}{.9\textheight}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've experimentally implemented that yesterday as well, and it does work. My issue since yesterday, however, is: This'll affect all single-column tb floats, not just the one type I want fixed on the outer columns. At the moment there aren't any, so this solution is sufficient for the time being, but that may change. Using [tb!] as you commented is indeed a workaround for that issue, but I'm worried that it carries other problems with it (given that it ignores all restrictions, not just this one).

Comment: The float options are reduced to bit flags, so creating a new one would affect an awful lot of code.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to handle it through a new float type vs. a new placement option? I'm not sure which function handles the decision if a current float can be placed somewhere, but could it be altered to take additional restrictions if float type is X; or is that too deep into the core?

Comment: I believe you are right.  The float type is packed into the same count register as the bit flags.  So the information is there, but obviously \@floatplacement won't handle it.  BTW, the queue consists of a macro delimited list (fancy).

Comment: The most I've ever attempted was in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page/426250?r=SearchResults&s=2|39.5185#426250

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it solves the issue as posted and it did ultimately help me solve the issue more specifically. I was able to take advantage of the fact that the float in question is the only one that takes up a whole column by its own, so instead of manipulating \@topnum and \@botnum I altered \@fpmin, \@textmin, \@toproom & \@botroom in the relevant columns so this particular float simply won't fit into the inner columns. Thanks.