# Figure on the bottom of the page

Tags: graphics

I am including a figure with following code which I expect to be shown at the end of the paragraph:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{direction}
    \caption{\textit{text caption}}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Instead, it is shown in the middle of the paragraph.
What should I change to make it show how I expect it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up isn't entirely clear: In the title, you mention wanting to place a `figure` object at the bottom of a page, while in the body of the posting, you say you expect the `figure` object to be placed at the end of a paragraph. The two objectives are neither complements nor mutually exclusive. E.g., a `figure` can be placed at the bottom of a page *and* be in the middle of a paragraph (say, because the paragraph isn't finished by the time the `figure` gets placed at the bottom of the page). Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This might help you: [Positioning of Figures](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures)

Comment: you haven't given any information to allow anyone to trace the issue but in `article` class bottom figures are is  at most 30% of `\textheight` so if your figure is bigger than that the the bottom area is not available.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page?r=SearchResults&s=1|50.4890

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers. Guess one of the things I have to learn besides how to write in latex is how to ask questions. The figure was on the bottom of the page but also happened to be in the middle of the paragraph. Adding [H] to\begin{figure} helped me to position the figure where I wanted.