# Split subfigures over two pages without text between them

Tags: positioning, subfloats, subfig

I would like to split 10 subfigures over two pages (6 at the bottom of one page, 4 at the top of the next page). I am using \ContinuedFloat for that. To set the position of the two blocks, I wrote [!b] and [ht] for each one, respectively.

However, I get a full page of text between the two blocks of figures. If I write [H] instead of [ht], I get the second block (figures 7-10) above the first one (figures 1-6).

Does anybody have an idea how to solve it?
Thank you in advance.

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!b]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig1}
\end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig2}
\end{subfigure}
\newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig4}
\end{subfigure}
    \newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig5}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering  
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig6}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig7}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig8}
\end{subfigure}
\newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig9}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig10}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Description }
    \label{fig:labelfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. I replaced the xxx.eps with test images of `width=0.5\linewidth` and added a `clearpage` after the sixth figure to clear the floats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text 

\begin{document}
\kant[1]    
    
\begin{figure}[!b]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
     \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-A} 
    \caption{fig1}
\end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{fig2}
\end{subfigure}
\newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps} 
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}  
    \caption{fig3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}       
    \caption{fig4}
\end{subfigure}
    \newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{fig5}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering  
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-B} 
    \caption{fig6}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 

\clearpage  % added

\begin{figure}[ht]
        \addtocounter{figure}{-1}  % added
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{6} % added
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-C} 
    \caption{fig7}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps} 
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}  
    \caption{fig8}
\end{subfigure}
\newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{fig9}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
      \includegraphics[ width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{fig10}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Description }
    \label{fig:labelfig}
\end{figure}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: outF1]

Since you are using two figures environments you need to set/reset the figure  and subfigure counters or use `\ContinuedFloat`  after starting the second figure.

Comment: Hi Simon,Thanks a lot for your reply. I appreciate it! It works now! However the numbering of the figures of the second block is now a, b, c, d..instead of g,h,i,j....
Do you know if it is posible to correct it? Thanks again!

Comment: @CRH  You are right. I updated the answer.

Comment: @ Simon Dispa, Perfect. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on [Place figure at bottom or top of next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page).  It allows one to break between any set of subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% missing files
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \def\reset#1{\ifnum\count#1=52 \global\count#1=54% [b]
    \else \ifnum\count#1=36 \global\count#1=54\fi% [b!]
    \fi}% convert [b] of [b!] to [bt]
  \let\@elt=\reset
  \@deferlist}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[b]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig1}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[b!]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig3}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig4}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[b!]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig5}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering  
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig6}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 
%
\begin{figure}[b!]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig7}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig8}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 
%
\begin{figure}[b!]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig9}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 430 0,clip, width=1.0\linewidth]{xxx.eps}  
    \caption{fig10}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Description }
    \label{fig:labelfig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```