# Preventing Floating Table in Middle of Breakable `tcolorbox`?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

I currently have breakable `tcolorbox`es and floating tables in proximity in my document.  In some instances, the `tcolorbox` will break and the table will (default) float to the top of the page and in the middle of the `tcolorbox`.

**Is there a way to give precedence to the broken tcolorboxes over floating objects so that the broken boxes are not interrupted by other objects?**  I'm reluctant to set `after=\clearpage` because I don't want a hanging blank page after the tcolorbox before content resumes.

MWE with `pdflatex` via TeXLive 2019:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,title=My breakable box]
  \lipsum[1-6]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  \begin{table}
  \caption{My Table}

  \centering{}%
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: If you use [ht] it will never go to the top of the first page.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page?r=SearchResults&s=1|79.2181

Comment: @JohnKormylo True, but I don't want to try to control my tables (and `tcolorboxes`) on a case-by-case basis.  This is for a *large* document with many such boxes and tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent a top float being on that page with `\suppressfloats[t]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,title=My breakable box]
  \lipsum[1-6]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \suppressfloats[t]

  \begin{table}
  \caption{My Table}

  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't known about `\suppressfloats`.  Two clarifications: (1) can this be used to put the float after the tcolorbox rather than at the bottom of the page and (2) is there a downside to putting `\begin{tcolorbox}[..., after={\suppressfloats[t]}]` or via `tcbset`?

Comment: The default is [tbp] (no [h]).  However you could append \supressFloat[t] to \endtcolorbox.

Comment: as @JohnKormylo says you would need to allow h so use `[htp]` or similar on the float. as well as stopping `t`.