# Not in outer par mod - Figure inside footnote

Tags: errors

I'm wondering how I can fix the error "not in outer par mode" in the following code. I'm adding a figure inside a footnote (I did it many times without any problem).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{integrazione temporale} (o \textbf{sommazione temporale}) quando uno stimolo viene applicato ripetutamente in una rapida successione, \ul{nello stesso punto}; in tal modo il potenziale graduato generato dalla prima applicazione dello stimolo \ul{non} si dissipa (completamente) prima che il potenziale graduato dello stimolo successivo venga generato, cioè il tempo tra uno stimolo ed il successivo è così breve che le depolarizzazioni degli stimoli si sovrappongono.
Maggiore è la sovrapposizione delle depolarizzazioni, maggiore è la sommazione temporale (maggiore è la depolarizzazione);
%
%
\item \textbf{integrazione spaziale} (o \textbf{sommazione spaziale}) quando si sommano gli effetti dei potenziali graduati \ul{generati quasi nello stesso istante ed in diverse regioni della membrana}.
\\
L'effetto di un potenziale graduato iperpolarizzante e di uno depolarizzante (generati quasi nello stesso istante in punt diversi della membrana) tendono a cancellarsi a vicenda.
%
%
\end{enumerate}
%
%
aaaaa%
\footnote
{
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{myimage}
%\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
%\includegraphics[width= cm]{fig1}
\caption{Integrazione temporale o spaziale nel neurone. (a) Convergenza di un ingresso dai neuroni W, X, Y e Z. I neurotrasmettitori dei neuroni W, Z e Z (in verde) producono depolarizzazione, mentre il neurotrasmettitore del neurone Y (in rosso) produce iperpolarizzazione della membrana postsinaptica. (b) La sommazione temporale dello stimolo W risultante in una depolarizzazione al di sopra del valore soglia e nella generazione di un potenziale di azione. (c) La sommazione spaziale degli stimoli W e X risultante in una depolarizzazione al di sopra della soglia e nella generazione di un potenziale di azione. (d) La sommazione spaziale degli stimoli W e Y non dà luogo ad alcuna modificazione del potenziale di membrana e, pertanto, non genera alcun potenziale di azione. (e) La sommazione spaziale degli stimoli W e Z non permette il raggiungimento del valore soglia in quanto il potenziale graduato, indotto dallo stimolo Z, si annulla a causa della grande distanza tra la sinapsi ed il monticolo assonale (è la parte dove si origina l'assone).}
\end{figure}
%
%
} 
si verifica solo parzialmente; maggiore è la larghezza dell'impulso di corrente, minore sarà l'integrazione temporale.
%
%
\end{enumerate}
%
%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A float in a footnote? Are you sure?

Comment: Hello @egreg I tried also without the [h] option, the result is the same.

Comment: I wanted to say that it doesn't make sense. If you really want to make a hard time for your readers, then use `[H]` with the `float` package, but you should rethink to the whole thing.

Comment: Perfect @egreg.

Comment: why a footnote??? Just use `\begin{figure][!b]` if you want a bottom float.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C39.1061

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle it's a figure related only to the text in the footnote...but maybe it's more beautiful the appearance given by your solution

Comment: you could use `\includegraphics` in a footnote, but using a captioned `figure`  in a footnote is very weird